# Identity Claim Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.Net MVC app that is using Azure B2C authentication, and identity roles to authorise users to access parts of the app.  However, there is an issue where, after around an hour, it appears that the roles are timing out.  My current theory is that, since it uses cookie authentication, the cookie is expiring and therefore the role is withdrawn.

The code to configure this is here:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
        SlidingExpiration = true
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication( ...
```

Note that no `ExpireTimeSpan` is set here.  The claims are added here:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
    {
        ...

        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();

            var myClaim = new Claim("Role", "admin");                
            identity.AddClaim(myClaim);
            ...
```

After timeout, `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims` are empty; so the custom claims that I'm adding, and the claims that MS issues (e.g. nameidentifier).  How is this getting cleared, and where is the setting (assuming it is a setting) that is telling it *when* to clear?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in setting

```
SlidingExpiration = true
```

while not setting

```
UseTokenLifetime = false
```

(in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)

Your id-token, issued by the identity provider expires in an hour (while the cookie does not). And can't be re-issued locally. A new challenge (roundtrip to IdP) should be performed to get a new token. Actually the behavior you explained (at some point still authenticated but missed all the cookie) looks buggy, but probably the explanation is not full enough.

Anyway if you would like to enlarge the identity token lifetime you can either change the setting in IdP (but not sure if Azure B2C offers such a setting), set `UseTokenLifetime = false` in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`, or issue your own token (with all the cookies you need and desired lifetime) on external authentication callback. But, once again, the simplest way is just to switch off sliding, rely on your external IdP and go for a new token when an old one expires.